# Wi-Fi list disabled for Ubuntu on Asus

Tags: networking, wireless, asus

I'm trying to display the list of connections available, but it doesn't show up.

The `lspci | grep -i net` command gives as a result:

```
02:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network
Adapter (rev 01)
03:00.2 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E
PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 06)
```

The `iwconfig` command shows:

```
eth0      no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"freebox_HQCMGK"
      Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Access Point:
    F4:CA:E5:D3:01:38
      Bit Rate=72.2 Mb/s   Tx-Power=16 dBm
      Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Power Management:off
      Link Quality=70/70  Signal level=-37 dBm
      Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
      Tx excessive retries:2  Invalid misc:77   Missed beacon:0

lo        no wireless extensions.
```

The problem is that I can access the Internet, but the Wi-Fi list doesn't show up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this command:

```
sudo iw dev {yourWlanIface} scan | grep SSID
```

Use the WLAN interface that you can search by using the command:

```
ifconfig
```

Because in [Ubuntu 16.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ubuntu_releases#Ubuntu_16.04_LTS_.28Xenial_Xerus.29) (Xenial Xerus) the interface's name changed a little bit.

It might help you.

Comment: This worked for me , but is there any solution to display the list with the wifi icon ?

Comment: Im not sure if i can help you with that, but you can try to use another driver to your wirelss card.

Comment: Go to system configuration>Software and updates>Another drivers and look for another driver.
Sorry if the names i gave you are different in your system, i havent my system in english.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
sudo iwlist wlan0 scan | grep ESSID
```